# How to push commit without adding the merge commit when there are updates in remote mainline

Tags: git

Say I pull the `mainline` of a repo, make some changes, added one commit `my_commit`. At the same time, someone else pushed `someone_commit` to remote `mainline`. Now if I want to push, if I do `git pull`, there will be conflicts and I have to add a `merge` commit. Is there a way I could achieve something like `previous_commits->someone_commit->my_commit` instead of `

```
previous_commits->someone_commit -> merge commits of ...
                ->my_commit      ->
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is the purpose of [`git rebase`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase).

Something like:

```
git rebase origin/mainline
```

This will reset your branch to mainline (with `previous_commits` at the tip), then replay your commits on top.

You will be prompted to resolve conflicts if there are any.

---

The following doesn't sound relevant to your current situation, but note that this will change the history of your local branch. If you have already pushed your local commits to a development branch, you will need to use a force push to rewrite the history on the remote development branch. But if, as you say, you and a colleague are working on the same branch, then this isn't likely to be a problem (and a force push on a shared branch can cause major issues)

Comment: So my current commit has HEAD->mainline which is one commit ahead from origin/mainline locally. My local origin/mainline is on commit behind remote. In this way `git rebase origin/mainline` doesn't seem to work?

Comment: Try `git fetch`. This should pull the origin's commits in your `origin/mainline` branch. (I'm assuming `mainline` is a branch name)